# How to get AWSCredentials from AWS NET SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net

I have .NET application which uses AWS SDK. This app sometimes uses
BasicAWSCredentials, sometimes uses
BasicAWSCredentials with SSO, and sometimes federated user account credentials.

I need to pass credentials into third party library. Is there way to use existing SDK `Credential and profile resolution` mechanism to retrieve credentials?

```
public void GetCredentialsDiscoveredBySdk()
{
    AWSCredentials credentials = ???
}
```

Why I don't use class like `AWSCredentialsFactory` and `CredentialProfileStoreChain`?

These classes require me to pass profile as an argument. I want profile to be automatically discovered from environment variables (i.e. `Aws__Profile`), and I don't want to recreate this in my code. Additionally sometimes I don't use profile (i.e. when using federated user accounts), so I would have to implement `Credential and profile resolution` mechanism myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials()
```

This is public type exposed by AWS SDK, so it should be safe to use it. Factory can be configured to include or exclude specific providers, which is very usefull.